# ASP.Net - Save previous Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method which save previous data in DataTable rows. I want to click "Create" previous rows data be maintained.

[image]

```
private void SetOldData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["Curtbl"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["Curtbl"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)myGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("txt1");
                    DateTimeControl dt1 = (DateTimeControl)myGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("dt1");
                    DateTimeControl dt2 = (DateTimeControl)myGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("dt2");
                    TextBox txt2 = (TextBox)myGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txt2");
                    TextBox txt3 = (TextBox)myGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txt3");

                    txt1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["txt1"].ToString();
                    dt1.SelectedDate = dt.Rows[i]["dt1"];
                    dt2.SelectedDate = dt.Rows[i]["dt2"];
                    txt2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["txt2"].ToString();
                    txt3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["txt3"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**My problem is conversion between this dates :**

```
dt1.SelectedDate = dt.Rows[i]["dt1"];
dt2.SelectedDate = dt.Rows[i]["dt2"];
```

Comment: Sorry, but your description tolds us nothing. Provide some more info: 1) paste error message; 2) what types are dt.Rows[i]["dt1"] and dt.Rows[i]["dt2"]? ; 3) what type is expected by "SelectedDate" property? but most important is your error message.

Comment: I want to save previous data in dateTimeConrols

Comment: where I click "Create" Button

Comment: DateTimeControl dt1  AND  DateTimeControl dt2

Comment: I understand what you wish to do, but please paste error message you receive.

Comment: Look down in my post..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since `SelectedDate` most likely needs a Datetime and the the `dt.Rows` most likely returns a string, you have to parse it to a datetime:

```
DataTime dateValue;
if (Datetime.TryParse(dt.Rows[i]["dt1"].ToString(), out dateValue))
{
       dt1.SelectedDate = dateValue;
}
```

(You provide very little details about error message etc...)

Comment: Maybe you need a `ToString()` on your `dt.Rows`. What does it say?